# Improving mysqltuner recommendations

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Problem with mysql under Ubuntu 20.04.0 in a CPU optimized droplet of 32GB RAM with 16 cores.

I have 25 sites installed on this server. I have around 100k pages views daily and during peaks around 300 connections to mysql. When a certain website which has a lot of users, when I upload a new post which requires to sign up to get access to it, mysql collapses and all sites gets down.

This is mysqltuner analysis, I´m stuck on how to improve it.

https://pastebin.com/Zfu9fScy

Any ideas on how to solve specifically these recommendations?

*** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
*** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)

Comment: I'll give you a more thorough analysis.  Follow the instructions here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
top -b -n 1 for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads mem and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: 400GB SSD (18% used)

A) https://jpst.it/2ZC7b
B) https://jpst.it/2ZC7q
C) https://jpst.it/2ZC7Q

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187870/275180

Comment: @mayomalo Any chance you could post the OS information requested?  Will help with best suggestions for workload analysis results.

Answer (score 0):

```
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.5.17-MariaDB-1:10.5.17+maria~ubu2004-log
- 32 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 21:41:20; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- 1.14e+3 QPS

**The More Important Issues:**

- Setting changes recommended:

  ```
    table_open_cache = 10000
    innodb_io_capacity = 10000
    innodb_io_capacity_max = 10000
    innodb_open_files = 10000
    max_heap_table_size = 512M
    table_definition_cache = 5000
  ```
- In general, do not blindly increase settings.  In some cases it leads to extra RAM allocations, which could lead to swapping, which is terrible for performance.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` seems to be bigger than necessary for the dataset size.  Later, if the dataset grows, consider raising the value.  (Stop before 70% of *available* RAM.
- Remove `innodb_log_files_in_group` before you upgrade to 10.6.  (It's presence may cause an error.)
- If you will be using text from places other than Western Europe, consider switching to utf8mb4.  (Beyond the scope of this discussion.)
- There seems to be a monitoring process that runs once a second.  (Cf Com_show_variables, Com_show_generic, Com_show_status, and especially Com_show_tables (19 /sec!))  Consider whether it might be slowing the system down more than it is worth.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is virtually useless, and is invasive.  It seems to be occurring (on average) twice a minute.

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((128M / 0.20 + 9728M / 0.70)) / 32768M = 44.4%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( table_open_cache ) = 247,485` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( Open_tables / table_open_cache ) = 5,205 / 247485 = 2.1%` -- Cache usage (open tables + tmp tables)
-- Lower table_open_cache (now 247485)

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 9,728 / 32768M = 29.7%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 9728M / 1 = 9728MB` -- Size of each buffer_pool instance.
-- An instance should be at least 1GB. In very large RAM, have 16 instances.  (`innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is ignored in 10.5.1.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,536 * 1 = 1,536` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 1). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,536` -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 465,304 * 16384 / 9728M = 74.7%` -- buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 500,000` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky. Use 2000 if using SSD drive.

`( innodb_io_capacity_max ) = 1,000,000 = 1.0e+6` -- When urgently flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 465,304 / 612940 = 75.9%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 10200547328) is bigger than necessary?

`( innodb_change_buffering ) = innodb_change_buffering = none`
-- Pre-5.6.11 / 5.5.31, there was a bug that made ="changes" a safer option. MariaDB 10.x.y is moving toward "none" and removing the setting and/or feature?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 2,418,868,224 / 9728M = 23.7%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( innodb_log_buffer_size ) = 2408M` -- Suggest 2MB-64MB, and at least as big as biggest blob set in transactions.
-- Adjust innodb_log_buffer_size (now 2524971008).

`( innodb_log_buffer_size ) = 2,408 / 32768M = 7.3%` -- Percent of RAM used for buffering InnoDB log writes.
-- Needs to be at least 10 times max blob size, but otherwise should not waste RAM with too big a value.

`( innodb_log_buffer_size / innodb_log_file_size ) = 2408M / 2048M = 117.6%` -- Buffer is in RAM; file is on disk.
-- The buffer_size should be smaller and/or the file_size should be larger.

`( innodb_log_files_in_group ) = 1` -- Number of InnoDB log files
-- removed in 10.6
Remove from config file.

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 78,080 / 60 * 2048M / 5138268672 = 543` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 2147483648). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = innodb_flush_neighbors = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 1` -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( max_connections ) = 5,000` -- Maximum number of connections (threads). Impacts various allocations.
-- If max_connections (now 5000) is too high and various memory settings are high, you could run out of RAM.

`( min( tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size ) ) = (min( 512M, 1024M )) / 32768M = 1.6%` -- Percent of RAM to allocate when needing MEMORY table (per table), or temp table inside a SELECT (per temp table per some SELECTs). Too high may lead to swapping.
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 536870912) and max_heap_table_size (now 1073741824) to, say, 1% of ram.

`( 176000 * max_connections ) = (176000 * 5000) / 32768M = 2.6%` -- Estimate of ram usage due to the size of max_connections.
-- max_connections (now 5000) is somewhat high

`( character_set_client ) = character_set_client = latin1` --

`( character_set_connection ) = character_set_connection = latin1` --

`( character_set_results ) = character_set_results = latin1` --

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (2110 + 1257054) / 89202925 = 1.4%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_tables ) = (6701709) / 78080 = 86 /sec` -- Frequency of creating "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = (2611985) / 78080 = 33 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size (now 536870912) and max_heap_table_size (now 1073741824).
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 2,611,985 / 6701709 = 39.0%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 536870912) and max_heap_table_size (now 1073741824); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( tmp_table_size ) = 512M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 536870912) to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( Com_show_variables ) = (78795) / 78080 = 1 /sec` -- SHOW VARIABLES ...
-- Why are you requesting the VARIABLES so often?

`( Com_optimize ) = (220384 + 109361 + 50 + 0 + 571666 + 1626) / 78080 = 0.037 /sec` -- How often OPTIMIZE TABLE is performed.
-- OPTIMIZE TABLE is rarely useful, certainly not at high frequency.

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Max_used_connections / max_connections ) = 79 / 5000 = 1.6%` -- Peak % of connections
-- Since several memory factors can expand based on max_connections (now 5000), it is good not to have that setting too high.

`( Com_change_db ) = (220384 + 109361 + 50 + 0 + 571666 + 1626) / 78080 = 7.4 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

`( Connections ) = (220384 + 109361 + 50 + 0 + 571666 + 1626) / 78080 = 7.4 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout (now 60); use pooling?

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 128 / 79 = 162.0%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

`( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536` -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc = 0
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay = 0
innodb_lru_scan_depth / innodb_io_capacity = 0.00307
query_cache_limit = 131,072
wait_timeout = 60
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) = 91.5
Access_denied_errors = 78,124
Aria_pagecache_reads = 31 /sec
Com_check = 0.037 /sec
Com_show_fields = 16 /sec
Com_show_generic = 1 /sec
Com_show_keys = 97 /HR
Com_show_status = 1 /sec
Com_show_tables = 19 /sec
Com_stmt_send_long_data = 30 /HR
Feature_json = 0.74 /sec
Feature_timezone = 2.9 /sec
Handler_discover = 3.7 /HR
Handler_read_last = 5.9 /sec
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written / Innodb_dblwr_writes = 122
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 576.1%
Innodb_num_open_files = 2,887
Open_streams = 4
Open_table_definitions = 2,992
Open_tables = 5,205
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost = 2,885
Sort_priority_queue_sorts = 15 /sec
Sort_range = 83 /sec
Sort_scan = 48 /sec
host_cache_size = 853
innodb_open_files = 500,000
max_heap_table_size = 1024MB
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size) = 512MB
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 222
table_definition_cache = 10,000
table_open_cache / max_connections = 49.5
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
concurrent_insert = ALWAYS
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
slave_parallel_mode = optimistic
sql_slave_skip_counter = 0
tx_isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 1M to reduce RAM reqd and handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 101,933
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 2M to reduce RAM reqd 
tmp_table_size=1G  # from 1/2G to match max_heap_table_size and reduce created_tmp_disk_tables RPS of 33 
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 0 for improved multi processing
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain  # from query_plan for more useful Slow Query Log
```

Observation:  Current select_scan RPS of 100 is due to lack of indexes where needed.

View profile please for contact info.  Many more tuning opportunities.

Comment: @mayomalo      Any feedback on better/worse after applying these suggestions?  Is your Slow Query Log more useful, since it include the EXPLAIN additional information?